# RunOnce key can't be run at startup with restricted public account in Windows

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-registry

Let me be brief. We have arround a 1000 public computers for users to use for the internet and office and so on. We image these using SCCM2012r2.

Everything is fine until we added a software package called Time Freeze which basically puts the computer back to the default after a restart. In my image I have captured, you can't have this software enabled because the sysprep/capture/deploy process will not work (think of steadystate). We have thought of a solution to enable the software using a command at start up, using RunOnce. The problem is that it seems to not run when the user "public" is logged on (autologon is enabled). We are looking for a way to get this command run at first logon of the public user. 
The command also enables the software to enable itself again at a restart, so this is all good.

The question is, is the HKLM RunOnce key restricted to run in a restricted account? GPO settins are enabled to restrict running .exe .bat etc. They can just open internet explorer and/or office products. Everything else is restricted.

Any ideas?